# Standardized tests questions databases

Tags: data-request

Are there open databases of questions from standardized tests (e.g. SAT, GMAT, GRE, etc)?

Comment: Yes, there  is .

Comment: @Unihedron It would be great if you could provide more information about relevant databases in an answer.

Comment: [National Center for Education Statistics](http://nces.ed.gov/nationsreportcard/naepdata/) by IES?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Unihedron

[National Center for Education Statistics](http://nces.ed.gov/nationsreportcard/naepdata/) releases a subset of questions.

I would not call this truly open, but it is a start.